# how to pass alphanumeric parameter in yii2 controller action

Tags: yii2

My code is

```
class WorkshopsController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = false;

    public function actionIndex($address)
    {
        echo $address;
        return $this->render('workshops.twig');
    }
}
```

I want to pass any place address to above given action. how can i do that in Yii2. Address can be like **"Mazyad Road, Mazyad - Al Ain - أبو ظبي - United Arab Emirates"**

Comment: I was having same problem. But here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988996/url-not-accepting-alpha-numeric-paramater-yii2-app-basic i got answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request you *workshops/index* page with *address* query parameter `example.com/workshops/index?address=some address`. Yii will automaticaly call your action and pass query params into it.

**EDIT**

If you wish to use pretty url, you must specify [urlManager rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules) for it. E.g.

```
rules => [
    'workshops/<address>' => 'workshops/index',
],
```

Also if you wish your page open when *addess* parameter not specified you can define rules like this:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'workshops/<address>',
    'route' => 'workshops/index',
    'defaults' => ['address' => ''],
]
```

Comment: Thanks ....

One thing more....
I have a folder named "customer" in "Controllers" folder. Now "customer" folder has its own related controller files. The URL should be like

"example.com/customer/documents/edit/1"

in above URL "customer" is a folder, "documents" is controller file, "edit" is a action and "1" is ID

now what would i do in URL Manager???

Comment: @abasit83 i suggest to you use module, to achieve this. See [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)