# URL not accepting alpha numeric parameter - Yii2-app-basic

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing, yii2-basic-app

As soon, i'm passing 41 in URL. confirm.php prints 41.

http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/confirm/41

But, when i pass "cfeb70c4c627167ee56d6e09b591a3ee" or "41a" in URL,

http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/confirm/41a

it shows error

> NOT FOUND (#404)
>   Page not found.
>
> The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact us if you think
>   this is a server error. Thank you.

I want to send confirmation id to user to confirm their account.
That's why random number "cfeb70c4c627167ee56d6e09b591a3ee" is being passed.

So, what can i do to make URL accept alpha numeric parameter.

**config/web.php**

```
'urlManager' => [
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionConfirm($id)
{
    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $this->view->params['customParam'] = $id;

    return $this->render("confirm",array("id"=>$id));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
'<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

to this

```
'<controller>/<action>/<id:[a-z0-9]+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

That should do it

Comment: Very nice Mr @Paladin. One thing more, do you have any documentation where this type of URL parameters are well described. If yes, then please share with me.

Comment: I will accept answer in few minutes. It working fine. Thanks

Comment: Here you have the link to the 2.0 documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Answer (score 2):

The current rule states that id is a number(`\d+`) hence it not working in your examples. Instead of modifying the current rule, I would add one specifically for this case:

```
'rules' => [
    'site/confirm/<id:\w+>' => 'site/confirm',
    '<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
],
```