# How to change url parameter like directory in Yii2?

Tags: php, url, yii2

I am using yii2.I have problem related to url structure. How I can change URL structure in Yii2 my current URL is given below

```
http://localhost/advanced/posts/view?id=1
```

My expected URL is

```
http://localhost/advanced/posts/view/id/1
```

I have follow the following link to change default URL of Yii2

[Yii2 htaccess - How to hide frontend/web and backend/web COMPLETELY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely)

Comment: set enableprettyurl to true in configuration

Comment: @InsaneSkull  pretty url is already enabled i think. Otherwise his "current URL" wont work.

Comment: prettyurl already enabled

Comment: You can set rules in config file.     'advanced/posts/view/<id>'  => '/advanced/posts/view' .

Comment: "id" in your expected url is confusing. Was that your intended url or this "http://localhost/advanced/posts/view/1"  ?

Comment: One thing i observed @InsaneSkull: This user has asked till date 6 questions. But, not accepted any answer. He is just simply asking question. Neither replying to any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Web.php**

```
'urlManager' => [
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller>/<action>/<id:d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

If Having **alpha numeric parameter**, then use.

```
'urlManager' => [
          'showScriptName' => false,
          'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<controller>/<action>/<id:w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
            ],
        ],
```

For More Info, click [URL Not Accepting Alpha Numeric Paramater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988996/url-not-accepting-alpha-numeric-paramater-yii2-app-basic)

Comment: Suggest using this instead of your rule; `'<controller>/<action>/<id:d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`, it's more precise and doesn't allow letters in the id

Comment: Ok. @JoeMiller . But, why i wrote `<id:[a-z0-9]+>` because if parameters will be like 41a. Means alpha numeric. Then, it can be helpful. In `<id:d+>`, alpha numerica parameter are not accepted.

Comment: Only because he's using an id as the parameter, id's are normally numeric only so that they can auto-increment in the database, otherwise you'd be better using `<id:w+>`, which will allow any normal word characters (letters and numbers). If you only have `[a-z0-9]` then it won't allow international characters, whereas I think `w+` will.

Comment: So, what you suggest @JoeMiller. `<id:d+>` or `<id:w+>` ?

Comment: For the OPs situation, as he's described it, `<id:d+>`would be better

Answer (score 1):

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [               
        'showScriptName' => false,  // Disable index.php
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // Disable r= routes
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                'mycategory/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                //Rules with Server Names
                'http://admin.domain.com/login' => 'admin/user/login',
                'http://www.domain.com/login' => 'site/login',
                'http://<country:\w+>.domain.com/profile' => 'user/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>-<slug:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => '<controller>/view',
            ),
    ],
],
```

and follow this link :
[first link](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/removing-index-php-from-url-in-yiiframework-2-0/)
[second link](http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/04/yii-url-manager-configuration/)